# How to use std::valarray in if statement without redundant computation?

Tags: c++, valarray

I have the following code with `float`, for example:

```
std::vector<float> v = {0.f, 1.f, 2.f};
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    if(v[i] != 0) // An optimization for `v[i] != 0`.
        v[i] = v[i] * v[i] * v[i]; // Time-consuming computation.
```

Now I want to replace `float` with `std::valarray<float>`:

```
using vfloat = std::valarray<float>;
std::vector<vfloat> v = {vfloat{0.f, 0.f}, vfloat{1.f, 0.f}, vfloat{2.f, 0.f}};
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    // if(v[i] != 0) // I want this optimization! ◀◀◀◄◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀◀
        v[i] = v[i] * v[i] * v[i]; // Time-consuming computation.
```

Though the new code is correct logically, there are redundant computation for `v[i][j] == 0`.

So how to use `std::valarray` in `if` statement without the redundant computation?

Comment: "Best" in what way? What problem do you face? Clarify.

Comment: you really want to turn on warnings

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Sorry for the unclarity. Now updated.

Comment: Use a nested loop

Comment: If you are asking how to check whether a valarray contains a non-zero element: `if ((v0[i] != 0).max())`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I want to do the time-consuming computation for each element.

Comment: What's stopping you? Go ahead and do it. I'm not sure I quite grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: I don't want to do the redundant computation `v[i] = v[i] * v[i] * v[i];` for `v[i] == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip elemets in `v[i]` use a nested loop

```
using vfloat = std::valarray<float>;
std::vector<vfloat> v = {vfloat{0.f, 0.f}, vfloat{1.f, 0.f}, vfloat{2.f, 0.f}};
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    for(size_t j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j)
        if (v[i][j] != 0)
            v[i][j] = v[i][j] * v[i][j] * v[i][j]; // Time-consuming computation.
```

or `apply`:

```
using vfloat = std::valarray<float>;
std::vector<vfloat> v = {vfloat{0.f, 0.f}, vfloat{1.f, 0.f}, vfloat{2.f, 0.f}};
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    v[i] = v[i].apply([](float n) -> float {
        if (n == 0) return 0;
        return n * n * n; // Time-consuming computation.
    });
```

If you want to skip elements in `v`

```
using vfloat = std::valarray<float>;
std::vector<vfloat> v = {vfloat{0.f, 0.f}, vfloat{1.f, 0.f}, vfloat{2.f, 0.f}};
for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    if ((v[i] != 0).max() != 0)
        v[i] = v[i] * v[i] * v[i]; // Time-consuming computation.
```

Answer (score 0):

there many options:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <algorithm>
// 2 loops in the worst case 
bool is_not_zero_0(std::valarray<float> const & v)
{
    return v.max() != 0.0 || v.min() != 0.0;
}

// one loop
bool is_not_zero_1(std::valarray<float> const & v)
{
    return std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(v), [](float item){return item != 0.0f;}) != v.end();
}
// 2 loops + allocation
bool is_not_zero_2(std::valarray<float> const & v)
{
    return (v != 0.0).max();
}
```